# Telethon with proxy ipv6

Tags: python, proxy, telegram, ipv6, telethon

I have problem in dealing with Telethon library when I use proxy ipv6 it show error
"An invalid argument was supplied" and some times "Proxy connection timed out: 10"

I used both python_socks and pysocks libraries same error

this is my code

```
import asyncio
 
 from telethon import TelegramClient, events
 
 api_id = valid
 api_hash = 'hidden'
 
 async def main():
     async with TelegramClient("session_name", api_id, api_hash,use_ipv6=True,proxy = {
     'proxy_type': 'http',
     'addr': 'ipv6',
     'port': port,
     'username': 'name',
     'password': 'pass',
     'rdns': True
 }) as client:
        await client.send_message('me', 'Hello, myself!')
 
 asyncio.run(main()
```

Comment: Which address scope are you using?

Comment: My address scope is GLOBAL-UNICAST

Comment: Does address scope affect my code?

Comment: If you are sourcing from, or you are sending to, a link-local address, e.g. sending to the proxy link-local address, the you can have problems. You cannot source from a link-local address for the public Internet, and if you are sending to a link-local address, you must include the Zone ID.